# Number of ways to select a sum with limited number of elements

Tags: combinatorics

I have coins with denominations $d_1$, $d_2$, $...$, $d_n$. For each of the coins I have the maximum number of these coins: $m_1$, $m_2$, $...$, $m_n$. I have to count the total number of ways I can select some price $M$.

For example if denominations are: `1, 2, 5, 10` and the maximum allowed number for each of the coins are: `2, 3, 1, 1` I can select the price `15` in two different ways: $10 + 5$ or $10 + 2 + 2 + 1$

---

This is the problem that I encountered in some programming competition. I was able to solve it easily by finding all positive solutions to a diophant  equation: $$\sum_{i=1}^n d_i \cdot m_i = M$$

---

The problem was that this problem is listed under combinatorics section and my solution does not look combinatorial to me. I would like to see whether there is a way to solve it using combinatorics, because I believe that this solution will broaden my horizons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ordinary generating functions. Note that Alex's statement about the NP-Completeness is still important and relevant here.

An ordinary generating function counts weighted objects. We use a formal power series, where the variable exponents are the weights. The coefficient of the variable is the number of configurations of elements which have that weight. So here, your weight is the monetary value. So $x^{0}$ represents a weight of $0$, while $x^{M}$ represents a weight of $M$.

Now for each denomination, we have the generating function:
$f_{d}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^{di} = \dfrac{1}{1-x^{d}}$, where the last equality comes from the identity for geometric series. Note that these series are formal; that is, we are not concerned with issues of convergence.

The generating function for selecting coins totaling to weight $M$ from your denominations is:

$g(x) = f_{d_{1}}(x) \cdot f_{d_{2}}(x) \cdot ... \cdot f_{d_{n}}(x) = \dfrac{1}{1-x^{d_{1}}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-x^{d_{2}}} \cdot ... \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-x^{d_{n}}}$

Now expanding out these generating functions, the coefficient of $x^{M}$ is your answer.

If you have limited quantities of the coins, then you adjust $f_{d}(x)$ as follows:

$f_{d}(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{m} x^{di} = \dfrac{1-x^{d(m+1)}}{1-x^{d}}$

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to solve this problem using combinatorics.  In fact, given a set-up like you did, the question of whether such a solution even exists is an NP-complete problem (called the [Knapsack Filling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)).  So, definitely no combinatorial answer better than what you provided.

Comment: It is a very strong statement **No way to solve using combinatorics**. I know that there is no polynomial solution for my problem, but this does not really means that there is no way to calculate the solution using combinatorics.

Comment: I thought the whole point of combinatorics was, to take something that does not have a closed form (e.g. exponential number of terms), and put it into a closed form that can be evaluated in much less time (e.g. polynomial).  I wrote a thesis based on combinatorics, with that understanding.  Maybe I am misunderstanding it?

Comment: I am not questioning your knowledge and I am sure you know combinatorics really well. Sorry if it sounded in this way. But in my opinion you can calculate something using combinatorics without providing a closed form solution. For example using combinatorics you can calculate the sum $1^k + 2^k + 3^k + .... + n^k$. This will not be a closed form solution, but still you can calculate it.